# Perl: Prompt appears to cause perl code to exit without giving correct output

Tags: perl

December 10, 2014

Can someone kindly help me to resolve this issue where character '>' causes the perl program to exit prematurely when run on a remote Windows server?

The actual output is:

```
K:\ Volume in drive K is DataDisk
 Volume Serial Number is E8BD-C593
 Directory of K:\
04/15/2011  05:25 AM    <DIR
```

The expected output is:

```
K:\>dir
 Volume in drive K is DataDisk
 Volume Serial Number is E8BD-C593

 Directory of K:\

12/08/2014  11:18 PM    <DIR>          ftpvol
04/15/2011  05:25 AM    <DIR>          Images
               1 File(s)              0 bytes
              16 Dir(s)  246,180,012,032 bytes free
```

Here is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Net::Telnet ();

my $node = $ARGV[0];
my $ipAddress = $ARGV[1];
my $username = $ARGV[2];
my $password = $ARGV[3];
my $mmlCommand0 = "hostname&prcstate -l";


my $filedate = `date +%Y%m%d`; #date in format YYYYMMDD
chomp($filedate); #deletes newline character at end 


my $numArgs = $#ARGV + 1;

if($numArgs == 4){

    my $telnet = new Net::Telnet( Host=>$ipAddress, Port=>23, Timeout=>20,  Errmode=>'die', Prompt=>'/>/');
    $telnet->open() or die "hai $telnet->errmsg ";
    $telnet->waitfor('/login name:/');
    $telnet->print($username);
    $telnet->waitfor('/password:/');
    $telnet->print($password);
    $telnet->waitfor('/Windows NT Domain:/');
    $telnet->print("");
    $telnet->waitfor('/>/');

## get printouts

    #print $telnet->cmd($mmlCommand0);

    print $telnet->cmd("K:");
    print $telnet->cmd("dir");
}
else{
    print "\n!!! Correct syntax is: command <node> <IP address> \nExample: \n\n";
}

print "\n\n";

exit(0);
```

script does not execute if I remove prompt or try to set another prompt.
However I think the error that the character '>' is always interpreted as the prompt.

```
my $telnet = new Net::Telnet( Host=>$ipAddress, Port=>23, Timeout=>20, Errmode=>'die');
$telnet->prompt('/$/');
```

Thanks in advance!

December 11, 2014

A "reply" button would be nice to have instead of having to edit an original port...

I am not quite following what Mr Llama has suggested. Accordingly if I am using the functions print() and waitfor() the promt should NOT be used. In that case I removed prompt however the code still does not work. Could you be kind to post a working code sample that will retrieve characters '<' and '>' in the printout and not treat either as a DOS prompt?

Answer (score 1):

The [`Net::Telnet`](http://search.cpan.org/~jrogers/Net-Telnet-3.04/lib/Net/Telnet.pm) documentation says that you only need to use the `prompt` attribute if you're *not* using `print()` and `waitfor()` for communication (it's meant to be used with `login()`.
In your case, the `prompt` value is being removed from the response.  Try setting the `prompt` value to something that will never occur and that should fix your issue.  Do be careful in what value you select as the `prompt` value will be treated as a regular expression.